# Problem with UITextView and frame task

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hi this is my UITextView coordinate on InterFace builder :
[image]

so if i want use this coordinate via frame task , my UITextView going to change the position on the screen !!! i don't know what's the problem ! i insert the exactly numbers on the interface builder size tab .

```
 textPad.frame = CGRectMake(511, 219, 751, 260);
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: what is the problem ?  whats happening now??

Comment: the problem is if i put this code on viewDid load ! my UITextView goes away !! from the screen !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone screen resolution is 320x480. 
(X:320
Y:480)
The point (0;0) is on the left up corner.

So you should chose like

```
textPad.frame = CGRectMake(20, 219, 751, 260);
```