# Force UITextView to scroll down on specific context

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextview

i have UITExtView with  `(511 , 369 , 571 , 519)` context , so my keyboard popups on UITextView  and filled some space on the screen , when users type some notes , the UITExtView 
text moves under the keyboard , i was wondering how should  implement specific context for textView to begin scroll down . i use this code but doesn't work !

```
[textPad scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(-120, 139, 751, 260) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present/2703756#2703756)

Take a look at this.  You'll have to manage your UITextView.  Though that example is about a UIScrollView, I think the same will apply to you for UITextView, if the Keyboard is obscuring it when it appears.

Comment: this is for the textfield and pop up keyboard to scroll the view , i made a custom keyboard , and have problem just with the context

Answer (score 0):

Resize the UITextView (change frame property) to fill only the visible space, when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: yes your right but i have this problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856399/problem-with-uitextview-and-frame-task

Comment: the view will be positioned in respect to the superview's position, maybe the superview has an incorrect position